# Use UISlider To Adjust iOS Font Size

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uislider, uifont

Currently inside my webView, I have two buttons to increase or decrease font size.  To save on space, I want to add a slider that can be pulled up to adjust the font size.  I have never used a slider before, and don't know where to start.  Here is the code for my two existing buttons:

```
- (IBAction)changeTextFontSizeSmaller
{
                textFontSize = (textFontSize > 50) ? textFontSize -5 : textFontSize;





    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'",
                          textFontSize];
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    [jsString release];
}
- (IBAction)changeTextFontSizeBigger {


    textFontSize = (textFontSize < 160) ? textFontSize +5 : textFontSize;



    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'",
                          textFontSize];
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    [jsString release];

}
```

Comment: Something along the lines of `textFontSize = (int)slider.value`?

Comment: Duh...I'm such an idiot.  Thanks

Comment: Don't be so harsh on yourself. I often struggle with the seemingly obvious. =)